# Flutter: How to set state of parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to change the color of a parent container with a button from a child widget.
Let's say I have a parentClass widget and a childClass widget. The container with dynamic color is in parentClass, and the button is in childClass. At first the container is blue and I want to make it red on button tap.

```
Color dynamicColor;

class ParentClass extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ParentClassState createState() => _ParentClassState();
}

class _ParentClassState extends State<ParentClass> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      dynamicColor = Colors.blue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ChildClass(),
        Container(
          color: dynamicColor,
          child: ...
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ChildClass extends StatefulWidget {
  ChildClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildClassState createState() => _ChildClassState();
}

class _ChildClassState extends State<ChildClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            dynamicColor = Colors.red; // What I want to do
          });
        },
        child: Text('Change parent container color'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function on parent widget and pass to child with parameter.
Like:

```
void delete() async {
  setState(() {
    dynamicColor = Colors.blue;
  });
 }
```

on your Widget Tree

```
 CustomChild(function: () => delete()),
```

Your custom Widget

```
class CustomChild extends StatelessWidget {
  Function function;
  CustomChild({this.function})
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And what if I want to pass a parameter to the function?

Comment: You use this function: (int id) => delete(id)

void delete(int id) async {
  setState(() {
    dynamicColor = Colors.blue;
  });
 }